# Descartes Rule of Signs gives wrong number of negative roots

Tags: calculus

Take three cases:

1. $f(x)=x^5-5x-4$
2. $f(x)=x^5-5x-3$
3. $f(x)=x^5-5x-5$

In all three cases, the coefficients of $f(x)$ has one sign change and $f(-x)$ has two sign changes. Hence, we conclude that we have $1$ positive root, and $2$ or $0$ negative roots. But, for case $(1)$, we have one positive root and *one* negative root. For other two cases, the principal is valid.

Please help me with this question.

Comment: Descartes counts roots with multiplicity.  in case (i) we have a double root at $x=-1$.